# Cleaning data in pandas not working as expected

Tags: pandas, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I have a Google Spreadsheet with info I've been gathering for a month.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSeua1He863Vya90JBlnkRvpyErGT6vQJKGmJAGE4F8wibw1LdiR9UKA_TTrVeAeaPzm86V4cE8cq6f/pubhtml

I'm trying to do some Data Analysis to find if there's a relationship between some factors (irrelevant to this question).

The problem is that when I'm cleaning the data, somethings don't go as I expected.
Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd


my_data = pd.read_csv('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSeua1He863Vya90JBlnkRvpyErGT6vQJKGmJAGE4F8wibw1LdiR9UKA_TTrVeAeaPzm86V4cE8cq6f/pub?output=csv', index_col=0)

# Check for impossible values
my_data = my_data[my_data['Agua'] < 5.0]
my_data = my_data[(my_data['Actividad física'] == 0) | (my_data['Actividad física'] == 1)]
my_data = my_data[(my_data['Baño'] >= 0) | (my_data['Baño'] <= 2)]

# Extract a list of meals taken (unique) to process them as proteins, carbs and fat.
meals = (my_data['Cena']+','+my_data['Almuerzo']+','+my_data['Merienda']+','+
my_data['Desayuno']).str.normalize('NFKD').str.encode('utf-8').str.decode('ascii', 'ignore').str.split(',').\
explode().str.strip().dropna().unique().tolist()

# Clean the resulting list up
for i in range(len(meals)):
    meals[i] = meals[i].replace('pasta ', '')
    if meals[i] == 'ananá':
        meals[i] = 'piña'
    elif 'papa' in meals[i]:
        meals[i] = meals[i].replace('papa', 'patata')
    elif meals[i][-1] == 's':
        meals[i] = meals[i][0:-1]
    elif 'pasta ' in meals[i]:
        print(meals[i])
        meals[i] = meals[i].replace('pasta ', '')
    elif 'gallet' in meals[i] or 'barrita' in meals[i]:
        meal = meals[i]
        meals.remove(meals[i])
        ingredients = meal.split('-')
        for j in range(len(ingredients)):
            if ingredients[j] == 'nueces':
                ingredients[j] = 'nuez'
        base, ingredient = ingredients[0].split(' ')
        meals.append(ingredient)
    elif 'choco' in meals[i]:
        meals[i] = 'cacao'
    
meals.append('galleta')
meals = sorted(list(set(meals)))
print(meals)
```

This code results in this list:

['aceituna', 'acelga', 'anana', 'arandano', 'asado', 'azucar', 'banana', 'berenjena', 'cacao', 'cafe', 'calabaza', 'carne', 'cerdo', 'choclo', 'crepe', 'fideo', 'frutillas', 'galleta', **'galletita banana-arandano'**, 'huevo', 'jengibre', 'leche', 'lemonie', 'limonada', 'mani', 'manteca', 'mate', 'melon', 'omelette', 'pan', **'pasta mani'**, 'patata', 'pescado', 'queso', 'quinoa pop', 'rucula', 'salsa tomate', 'tomate', 'tortilla patata', 'uva', 'zanahoria', 'zapallo']

I've highlighted the 2 problems I've encountered so far. This code should eliminate both 'pasta mani' and 'galletita banana-arandano' from the list (converting them into something else).

For 'pasta mani' I've noticed that if in `meals[i] = meals[i].replace('pasta ', '')` I type 'ta' instead of pasta, it works. I don't understand what's the problem with the 'pas' part of the string.

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your major issue was deleting an element of the list and appending it which caused problems while iterating over every item. Instead of modifying every item of list you should create a new list and move the "Remove the plural s" condition as a separate if statement

```
meals = ['tira de asado', 'papa', 'tomate', 'rucula', 'limonada', 'melon', 'queso', 'pan', 'pasta aceituna', 'mate', 'azucar', 'quinoa pop', 'banana', 'leche', 'cafe', 'huevos', 'arandanos', 'crepe', 'acelga', 'choclo', 'zanahoria', 'zapallo', 'galletita mani-nueces-cacao', 'pasta mani', 'uvas', 'huevo', 'omelette', 'anana', 'merluza', 'tortilla papa', 'berenjena', 'salsa tomate', 'barrita choco-mani-avena', 'frutillas', 'calabaza', 'mani', 'carne', 'cerdo', 'fideos', 'lemonies', 'galletita banana-arandanos', 'jengibre', 'manteca']
out = []

# Clean the resulting list up
for word in meals:
    if word[-1] == 's':
        word = word[0:-1]

    if word == 'ananá':
        word = 'piña'
    elif 'papa' in word:
        word = word.replace('papa', 'patata')
    elif 'pasta ' in word:
        word = word.replace('pasta ', '')
    elif 'gallet' in word or 'barrita' in word:
        ingredients = word.split('-')
        word = "galleta"        
        for j in range(len(ingredients)):
            if ingredients[j] == 'nueces':
                ingredients[j] = 'nuez'
        base, ingredient = ingredients[0].split(' ')
        out.append(ingredient)

        
    elif 'choco' in word:
        word = 'cacao'
    out.append(word)

out = sorted(list(set(out)))
print(out)
```

The result than looks like expected:

> ['aceituna', 'acelga', 'anana', 'arandano', 'azucar', 'banana',
> 'berenjena', 'cafe', 'calabaza', 'carne', 'cerdo', 'choclo', 'choco',
> 'crepe', 'fideo', 'frutilla', 'galleta', 'huevo', 'jengibre', 'leche',
> 'lemonie', 'limonada', 'mani', 'manteca', 'mate', 'melon', 'merluza',
> 'omelette', 'pan', 'patata', 'queso', 'quinoa pop', 'rucula', 'salsa
> tomate', 'tira de asado', 'tomate', 'tortilla patata', 'uva',
> 'zanahoria', 'zapallo']